# how can i set observer threshold in zhbhun/react-native-intersection-observer

Tags: react-native, intersection-observer

When I use the Intersection Observer, for example, when my cards are repeated in a flatlist, I want to set a threshold so that the observer only recognizes each card when it is at least 70% visible on the screen.

```
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView} from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import {
  IOScrollView,
  IOScrollViewController,
  InView,
  IOFlatListController,
  IOFlatList,
} from 'react-native-intersection-observer';

interface ItemProps {
  title: string;
}
const DATA = [
  {
    id: '1',
    title: 'First Item',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    title: 'Second Item',
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    title: 'Third Item',
  },
  {
    id: '4',
    title: 'Forth Item',
  },
  {
    id: '5',
    title: 'Fifth Item',
  },
  {
    id: '6',
    title: 'Sixth Item',
  },
  {
    id: '7',
    title: 'Seventh Item',
  },
  {
    id: '8',
    title: 'Eighth Item',
  },
  {
    id: '9',
    title: 'Ninth Item',
  },
  {
    id: '10',
    title: 'Tenth Item',
  },
];

const Item: React.FC<ItemProps> = ({title}) => (
  <InView onChange={(inView: boolean) => console.log(inView, title)}>
    <View style={{borderWidth: 1, height: 300, margin: 20}}>
      <Text>{title}</Text>
    </View>
  </InView>
);

const Observer: React.FC = () => {
  const scrollViewRef = useRef<IOFlatListController>(null);

  const renderItem = ({item}: {item: {id: string; title: string}}) => (
    <Item title={item.title} />
  );

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{backgroundColor: 'orange', flex: 1}}>
      <IOFlatList
        style={{borderWidth: 2, backgroundColor: 'white'}}
        ref={scrollViewRef}
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default Observer;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDwDE.png)

For example, if I've set a threshold, then right now, the first card should indeed be considered as "in view" with the **`inView`** value being true in the **`onChange`** function because it's more than 70% visible on the screen. However, I want the second card to not be considered "in view" yet as it hasn't reached the 70% visibility threshold.

Is there a way to set the threshold for Intersection Observer similar to how it's done with the web's observer?

https://github.com/zhbhun/react-native-intersection-observer
here is zhbhun/react-native-intersection-observer github

i want set the threshold